# How can I only colour my hyperrefs, without colouring section numbers, figure numbers and table of contents?

Tags: hyperref

How can I only have my hyperrefs (i.e. something like this: `\href{http://www.overleaf.com}{Something  Linky}`) coloured, without colouring my table of contents, figure numbers and chapter numbers? I still want the table of contents, figure numbers and chapter numbers to be clickable, but not coloured.

For example, I have my hyperref set up as follows:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    }
```

However, this not only colours my hyperrefs blue, but also my table of contents, my figure numbers `(Figure~\ref{fig:name_of_fig})`, and my chapter numbers `(Chapter~\ref{sec:name_of_chapter}`.

Comment: Note it is good practice to provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is (instead of a code sniplet like this which cannot be tested without adding code)

Comment: Also not that `...color` are not true false variables they should point to color names (don't ignore compilation errors)

Comment: `\href` and `\url` are URL links and have the `urlcolor`. Just set the other colors to black.

Comment: And `urlcolor` to whatever else except black.